# Рисование графика на Panel или PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, графика, график

Здраствуйте! Нужно нарисовать график функции y=(1-х^2)(x-2) (-2<x<2). При этом нужно использовать Radiobutton и RadioGroup для выбора цветов и шрифтов надписей, а также для построения осей координат. График должен выводится в анимационном режиме с использованием компонента Timer. Я новичок в этом деле и не совсем понимаю как это делать. Сделал, что-то вроде такого, но при этом если я нажима на Radiobutton, ничего не рисует. Как только я сворачиваю окно и открываю заново, уже нарисовано. Может ли кто-то помочь в этом разобраться? Я очень много прошу, но хотел бы что-бы мне подсказали как правильно нарисовать график с использованием RadioButton и Timer. Буду очень признателен!

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private int xMin = -15;
        private int xMax = 15;
        private int yMin = -15;
        private int yMax = 15;

        private int dx, dy;
        private int x0, y0;

        bool shouldPaint = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }


        private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Refresh();
            panel1.Refresh();
        }

        
        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            dx = panel1.Width / (xMax - xMin);
            dy = panel1.Height / (yMax - yMin);
            x0 = -dx * xMin;
            y0 = dy * yMax;
            //panel1.Controls.Add(radioButton10);
            
            for (int x = xMin; x <= xMax; x++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.LightBlue, x0 + x * dx, 0, x0 + x * dx, panel1.Height);
            }
            //panel1.Refresh();

            if (radioButton10.Checked)
            {
                shouldPaint = true;
                //if (!RenderOk) { return; }
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
                // ось абсцисс
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, y0, panel1.Width, y0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новичкам давать такие задачи...
RadioGroup - панель для Radiobutton, чтобы когда нажимаешь на один Radiobutton - с другого снималась отметка в том-же RadioGroup. Сам по себе выбор Radiobutton не должен запускать никаких процессов, это настройка.
Должна быть отдельная кнопка, запускающая процесс рисования.
Что с таймером, что без таймера - вариантов ка это сделать - много, какая задача - такое решение, целенаправленно ищем самый тупой вариант.
Xmin и Xmax у вас в диапазоне [-2,2]

```
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
List<Point> points = new List<Point>(); //для хранения точек
int y(int x) => (1 - x * x)*(x - 2);

void Start(Control panel) //(-2 < x < 2)
{
    if (paintactive) return;
    paintactive = true;
    //y=(1-х^2)(x-2) (-2<x<2)
    points.Clear();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    int x = -2;
    timer.Tick += (s, a) =>
    {
        if (x <= 2)
        {
            var point = new Point(x, y(x));
            //WriteLine(point);
            points.Add(point);
            x++;
            panel.Invalidate();
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            paintactive = false;
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}

void Panel_Paint(object s, PaintEventArgs a)
{
   a.Graphics.DrawLines(p, points.ToArray());
}
```

Запуск рисования происходит командой:

```
Start(panel);
```

Comment: можете довести код до ума если я вам скину проект?

Comment: А что с ним не так?

Comment: та не могу с таймером разобратся

Comment: И что с ним не так?

Comment: вот смотрите, можно ли сделать так чтобы при клике на кнопку рисовалась ось при этом параметры рисование выбирались с помощью Radiobutton.Checked?

Comment: @Parasha ось может быть всегда, поэтому рисование оси можно добавить в Panel_Paint первой строкой, там же и сделать проверку radio-button'ов. При смене этих настроек можно запускать panel.Invalidate(); чтобы принудительно обновлять ось.

Comment: спасибо, попытаюсь разобраться, если будут вопросы, еще спрошу Вас

Comment: можете посмотреть проект, если у Вас есть время, что-то не так с таймером у меня

Comment: @Parasha скидывайте

Comment: только смотрите, мне нужно рисовать не на панельке,  а на форме просто, поэтому я пробовал именно на форме. И как вам можно скинуть?

Comment: прикрепляю вам ссылку на гугл диск https://drive.google.com/file/d/15V8kCK7Yk1shKRuRV7ZZv31NOF9Mx0Xv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: получилось что-то изменить?

Comment: В Form1_Paint уберите timer1_Tick(); и удалите нахрен OnLoad(); В button2_Click добавьте pointCounter=3; и timer1.Interval=10; уберите timer1.Enabled=false; и добавьте timer1.Enabled=!timer1.Enabled; В timer1_Tick уберите timer1.Enabled=true; и в условии уберите pointCounter=3; и добавьте timer1.Enabled=false; само условие измените на (++pointCounter>=(pointsToScreen?.Length??0)) В самом классе измените private int pointCounter=0; У меня осталось слабое мерцание, фиксится добавлением Form1_Load(){ DoubleBuffered=true;} И ради Всеотца Одина - не используйте подобные косытыли типа pointCounter!

Comment: @Parasha Единственное что запускается со второго нажатия "Нарисовать график".

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, очень помогли!!! Один вопрос только: что означает условие pointsToScreen?.Length??0?

Comment: int что-то = pointsToScreen != null ? pointsToScreen.Length : 0;

Comment: @Parasha Объект?.(метод или свойство или поле) - возвращаем свойство или поле или результат метода (есть ограничения) если объект не null, а если null - не обращаемся к сущностям объекта чтобы не вызвать ошибку а просто возвращаем null. А "??" объединение с null, например "= Объект ?? другой объект" - если Объект != null, то возвращаем его, а если Объект == null - то возвращаем "другой объект". Во всём этом есть особенности типов, почитайте про оператор "?." и Nullable<> типы. Очень помогает и позволяет минимизировать разные проверки.

Comment: спасибо Вам еще раз, огромное!!!